# Need help making a Python script starup on mac using Launch Agent and send output to a window

Tags: python, launchd, startupscript

I've created a python script I wish to have run automatically when I log in on a mac, and need some help using a Launch Agent to do this. I used SO extensively getting things working up to this point, so I figured this was the place to ask, but I'm still fairly new to this, so I need some help.

Here's what I've got so far and what I still need:

I have a python script that I can run from the terminal. It periodically will output text to the terminal window whenever it does something important (uses the python 'print' command). It also creates a log of this elsewhere, but I also want the realtime update in a window that stays open.

What I now need is a Launch Agent to start this script automatically on login and still output this text. I've gotten a basic Launch Agent working, but it runs the script in the background and I no longer can see the output. Based on my research so far, it looks like I can use the "StandardOutPath" keyword in the Lauch Agent .plist to redirect this output? I don't yet understand stdout/stdin/stderr in these programs well enough to understand how all of this works, but I was hoping to essentially redirect this output, perhaps to an xterm window or similar.

I couldn't find a good example of this type of thing anywhere, so there may be a better way to do it, and I'm just not searching for the right thing. Any help or explanation on how all this works would be much appreciated.

Updated:
My working Launch Agent .plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.name.WVCS-0.1</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/Path/to/StartupScript</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the output to appear in a terminal, you can use Launch Agent to start an Apple Script which will open Terminal and then run your python script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "/usr/bin/python WVCS-0.1.py"
end tell
```

or to display the text in the applescript / calling window

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do shell script "/usr/bin/python WVCS-0.1.py"
end tell
```

And then change your plist so that

```
<array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>/path/to/that/script</string>
</array>
```

Not super elegant, but I hope that helps!

Comment: Well, this worked to run it, but unfortunately it is still not outputting to a window. If I just run the applescript the output shows up in the Applescript Editor window under output. It seems this script grabs output from the shell command rather than running the command in the Terminal window that was just opened.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - in which case you want `do script "/usr/bin/python /path/to/WVCS-0.1.py"`